# Sum of a column display in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table where I have three particular transactions: Billing, Penalty and Discount. I want to compute the billed amount ((Billing - Discount)+Penalty).

```
| CustNumber | Particular | Amount |
| 1001       | Billing    | 170.00 |
| 1001       | Penalty    | 17.00  |
| 1001       | Discount   | 8.50   |
| 1002       | Billing    | 250.00 |
| 1002       | Penalty    | 25.00  |
| 1002       | Discount   | 12.50  |
| 1003       | Billing    | 500.00 |
| 1003       | Penalty    | 50.00  |
| 1003       | Discount   | 25.00  |
| 1004       | Billing    | 200.00 |
| 1004       | Penalty    | 20.00  |
| 1004       | Discount   | 10.00  |
```

This should be the output

```
| CustNumber | BilledAmount |
| 1001       | 178.50       |
| 1002       | 262.50       |
| 1003       | 525.00       |
| 1004       | 210.00       |
```

What I have tried so far: I managed to get the billed amount for each individual account:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spComputeBilledAmount]
    @CustId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @billing decimal(18,2),
            @penalty decimal(18,2),
            @discount decimal(18,2)

    SELECT 
        @billing = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN particulars = 'Billing' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END), 0),
        @penalty = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN particulars = 'Penalty' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END), 0),
        @discount = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN particulars = 'Discount' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END), 0)
    FROM
        [Transactions]
    WHERE 
        [ConcessionaireId] = @CustId
                            
    SELECT ((@billing-@discount)+ @penalty)  AS 'BilledAmount'
END
```

Comment: Why do you think you need COALESCE? Presumably the Amount column is not nullable (which would be logical nonsense). Do you see the assumption in the suggestion you marked as answer? Do you understand how it is very different from your logic? Do not blindly choose an answer without thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    CustNumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Particular = 'Billing' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) +
    MAX(CASE WHEN Particular = 'Penalty' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN Particular = 'Discount' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS BilledAmount
FROM [Transactions]
GROUP BY
    CustNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure only handle one `CustNumber` at a time. It is not practical anyway, you don't need a stored procedure to do this.

```
SELECT t.CustNumber,
       SUM 
       ( 
           CASE Particular
           WHEN 'Billing'  THEN +t.Amount 
           WHEN 'Penalty'  THEN +t.Amount 
           WHEN 'Discount' THEN -t.Amount 
           END
       ) AS BilledAmount 
FROM   [Transactions] t
GROUP BY t.CustNumber
```

Comment: The simple case form is far easier to read and understand.